# How can I use Guice in Glassfish 3?

Tags: java, web-services, dependency-injection, glassfish, jersey-1.0

My ear is using CDI but I'm running into [known](http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2010/11/cdi-major-risk-factor-in-java-ee-6.html) [memory](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18768) [leaks](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20474).  Rather than drop dependency injection all together, I'm wondering if it's possible to replace the CDI code with Guice code.

I'm using the Stripes framework, Web Services and Jersey 1.x.  How can I get Guice to manage all these end points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [To get Guice working in web services](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/guice/)
- [To get Guice working in Stripes framework](http://bgoodin.github.io/stripes-guice/)
- [To get guice working in Jersey 1.x](https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes//posts/jersey_guice_rest_api)